# Passing array in parameter with Alamofire (.GET)

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire 3.0
The following is my code

```
var ignoreIDs = [Int]()
self.ignoreIDs.append(2)
let parameters = ["ignore_ids": self.ignoreIDs]
Alamofire.request(.GET, AppDelegate.kbaseUrl + "surveys/me", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
    .responseJSON {
        response in
    }
```

However, the result of print(response.result) just shows FAILURE. 
Is there any way to get more information? Also, is this the correct way to pass an array as parameters?
P/S: Yes server side is indeed expecting an array.

Comment: For more information you may do this: `.responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in` instead `.responseJSON { response in`. And print all params you need

Comment: Is it just me or you can't do that since Alamofire 2.0? I'm using Alamofire 3.0

Comment: I did not know that this does not work in 3.0. I use old version. I'm sorry for the wrong information

Comment: add the exact format of array which server is expecting and also the returning result from server as well

Comment: Johnny can you elaborate a bit? At least how can I get more info at this point?

Comment: I now use debugPrint and got the following result

    FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1017 "cannot parse response" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1360a3c50 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1017 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://testing.com/api/surveys/me, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://testing.com/api/surveys/me, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1, NSLocalizedDescription=cannot parse response}

Any ideas?

Comment: i meant server is expecting {"ignore_ids": "XXX"}  or ["ignore_ids": "XXX"] ?

Answer (score 2):

To print out additional information about the result, you should use `debugPrint(response.result)`.

```
var ignoreIDs = [Int]()
self.ignoreIDs.append(2)
let parameters = ["ignore_ids": self.ignoreIDs]

Alamofire.request(.GET, AppDelegate.kbaseUrl + "surveys/me", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
    .responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)
        debugPrint(response.result)
    }
```

Both of these are overridden to provide more detail about the actual response.

Answer (score 0):

sorry apparently it's my own fault. My method is a GET, so as Johnny mentioned I'm parsing in a form that the server wasn't expecting.

The answer for me should be append the parameters as a query string and to my base url.